# Calculating size of the page table

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

Consider a machine with 64 MB physical memory and a 32-bit virtual address space. If the page size is 4 KB, what is the approximate size of the page table ?

My Solution:

```
Number of pages in physical memory = (size of physical memory)/(size of page)
                                   = 64 * 2^10 / 4
                                   = 2^14
Number of pages in virtual memory = (size of virtual memory)/(size of page)
           size of virtual memory = 2^32 bits
                                  = 2^29 bytes
                                  = 2^19 kBytes
Number of pages in virtual memory = 2^19/4 = 2^17
=> Number of entries in page table = 2^17
Size of each entry = 17+14 =31 bits
Size of page table = 31 * 2^17 bits 
                   = 31 * 2^14 bytes
                   = 31 * 2^4 KB
                   = 31*16
                   = 496 KB
```

But the answer is 8 MB. Why?

Answer (score 3):

8MB cannot be the answer,
**Physical Address Space** = 64MB = 2^26B
**Virtual Address** = 32-bits, ∴ **Virtual Address Space** = 2^32B
**Page Size** = 4KB = 2^12B
**Number of pages** = 2^32/2^12 = 2^20 pages.

**Number of frames** = 2^26/2^12 = 2^14 frames.

∴ **Page Table Size** = 2^20×14-bits ≈ 2^20×16-bits ≈ 2^20×2B = 2MB.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been asked before. However, there is not sufficient information in the question to determine the size of the page table.

1. It does not specify the size of the page table entries.
2. It does not specify the number of pages mapped to the process address space.
3. It does not specify the division between the process and system address pace. How much of the 32 bits is part of the process address space.
4. It does not specify whether this is a process or system table.

Answer (score -1):

there is error in question virtual address if of 34 bits for this question answer is 8 MB and for given question answer will be 2 MB